# The shortest "time ago"

Tags: date, nsdatecomponents, nsdatecomponentsformatter

I created a function which very nice compare two dates and return difference as String

```
extension Date {
    var shortTimeAgo: String {
        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.allowedUnits = [.year,.month,.weekOfMonth,.day,.hour,.minute,.second]
        formatter.maximumUnitCount = 1
        formatter.unitsStyle = .short
        return formatter.string(from: self, to: Date())
    }
}
```

But it returns values like "35 sec", "10 min" or even "2 days 1 hr"

How to get even shorter values like "35s", "10m" and just "2d" ?

Comment: Did you read the documentation of the other contants of `UnitsStyle`? Did you try them?

Comment: yes, option .short is the shortest possible but is still to long ;)

Comment: Did you try `abbreviated`? The documentation says: A style that uses the most abbreviated spelling for units. The abbreviated style represents the shortest spelling for unit values. For example, one hour and ten minutes is displayed as “1h 10m”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code -

```
extension Date {
    var shortTimeAgo: String {
        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.allowedUnits = [.year,.month,.weekOfMonth,.day,.hour,.minute,.second]
        formatter.maximumUnitCount = 1
        formatter.unitsStyle = .abbreviated
        return formatter.string(from: self, to: Date())
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!